# An onClick() event works on one div, but not another. Why?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

Using React, I have one div that contains information, and another div inside of it that contains a list of items. I want this second div(the list) to be collapsible on click. If I put the click listener into the first div, it works and shows the list of items. The problem with this is that it shows all of the lists for all of the items. I want only the list of the clicked item to be visible:

```
render() {
        return (
            this.state.data.map(item => {
                return (  // If I put onClick={this.showCollapsible} here, all lists are loaded
                    <div id={'imageTableItemComponent'} key={item.imageName}>
                        {item.imageName} -
                        {item.tags.length}
                        <div id={'collapsibleTagList'} key={item.tags} onClick={this.showCollapsible}>
                               // *** This onClick does not get triggered ***
                            {this.state.collapsible && <TagTableComponent data={item} onClose={() => this.hideCollapsible()}/>}
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                )
            })

        )
    }
```

If I add parenthesis after `this.showCollapsible()`, I get this warning:

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Here is the showCollapsible function:

```
showCollapsible = () => {
        this.setState( {collapsible: true})
    }
```

My list should look like this:

- image1
- image2
- image3
  -item1, item2, item3 (When item3 is clicked)

With the onClick listener in the first div, all lists are opened like so:

- image1 -item1, item2
- image2 -item1, item2, item3, item4
- image3 -item1, item2, item3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've changed a few things. Firstly, when I asked the question my `constructor` looked like this:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data : [],
            collapsible : false,
        }
    }
```

I've changed collapsible to null, `collapsible: null,` and changed my `showCollapsible` function to look like this:

```
showCollapsible = (imageName) => {
        this.setState( {collapsible: imageName})
    }
```

And to finish, I call on the click listener in the 1st div, like so:

```
 render() {
        return (
            this.state.data.map(item => {
                return (
                    <div id={'imageTableItemComponent'} key={item.imageName} onClick={() => this.showCollapsible(item.imageName)}> <!-- This looks fancy, eh? -->
                        {item.imageName} -
                        {item.tags.length}
                        <div id={'collapsibleTagList'} key={item.tags}>
                            {this.state.collapsible === item.imageName && <TagTableComponent data={item} onClose={this.hideCollapsible}/>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })

        )
    }
```

For anyone who might run into this problem in the future, don't do what I did first XD

By setting collapsible to true, it changed state for the entire class, so it didn't matter where I changed the state. This way, the state only gets changed for the item that has the correct imageName.